# How to bind to a control element within a ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, binding, resourcedictionary

I'm trying to refer to an element in my WPF Control from within a ResourceDictionary on that control. Here's an example:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Behaviors:GridViewInteractionModel x:Key="gridViewInteraction" GridView="{Binding ElementName=myGridView}"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
...
<SomeGridView x:Name="myGridView"/>
```

The value of the `GridView` dependency property on the `GridViewInteractionModel` object should be the `SomeGridView` object called `myGridView`.

**The above code doesn't work.** `{Binding ElementName=myGridView}` does not bind the element (the SetValue function of `GridViewInteractionModel` never gets called).

The WPF runtime error is:

```
Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=myGridView'.
BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 
'GridViewInteractionModel' (HashCode=15238415); target property is
'GridView' (type 'SomeGridView')
```

Does anyone know how to get an element within the control to be bound to a property of a resource within the ResourceDictionary?

The only way I've found to get the property set is by manually setting it in the code-behind constructor like this, after `InitializeComponent()` has been called:

```
(Resources["gridViewInteraction"] as GridViewInteractionModel).GridView = FindName("myGridView") as SomeGridView;
```

But that's really ugly (and error-prone).

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve here. This is an example of how I have dealt with a listview and it's child items:

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewStyle" TargetType="ListView">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFD3D1CF" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.7"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF494646"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFDFAFA"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"></Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>


<ListView x:Name="lvwSettingsYears" x:Uid="lvwSettingsYears" Margin="10,77,10,50"
    Style="{DynamicResource ListViewStyle}"
    ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListViewItemStyle}"
    SelectionChanged="lvwYears_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="SettingsYearListviewID" x:Uid="SettingsYearListviewID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding id}" Width="0"/>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="SettingsYearListviewCode" x:Uid="SettingsYearListviewCode" Header="Code" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Code}" Width="100"/>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="SettingsYearListviewDesc" x:Uid="SettingsYearListviewDesc" Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" Width="300"/>
        </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
 </ListView>
```

What prompted me to post this is in your error message it mentions 
target property is
'GridView' (type 'SomeGridView')

I think it is looking for the control type.

Comment: That's not quite either ... the resource is within a `ResourceDictionary`. Trying to use `DynamicResource` gives an error that the object needs to be a DependencyObject (but `GridViewInteractionModel` is a `Behavior<SomeGridView>` object).